# Wedderburn decomposition of twisted group algebras

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $K$ be a field and $G$ be a finite group. Maschke's theorem states that the group algebra $KG$ is semisimple iff $|G|$ is not divisible by $\text{char}K$. In particular, if $\text{char}K=0$, the group algebra $KG$ is always semisimple.

Now let $\alpha\in Z^2(G,K^{\times})$ be a $2$-cocycle with coefficients in $K^{\times}$ (with the trivial action) and define a new multiplication in the vector space $KG$, namely
\begin{equation*}
\mu\colon KG\times KG\to KG \\
(g,h)\mapsto \alpha(g,h)gh.
\end{equation*}

This is indeed again an algebra called $\textit{twisted group algebra}$ denoted by $K_\alpha G$. Two such algebras $K_\alpha G$ and $K_\beta G$ are isomorphic iff $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are cohomologous.

It is also known that a twisted group algebra $K_\alpha G$ is semisimple if $|G|$ is not divisible by $\text{char}K$, but the converse is not true anymore. Lets assume that this holds, i.e. $K_\alpha G$ is semisimple.

**Question:** Is anything known about the Wedderburn decomposition of $K_\alpha G$? If not, are there results in the special case that $G$ is a finite abelian group?

Comment: There's a central extension $N \hookrightarrow H \twoheadrightarrow G$, where N is the f.g. Abelian group generated by the image of the cocycle, such that $K_\alpha G$ is a quotient of $KH$. However, knowing which simple factors of $KH$ get killed by this quotient seems difficult in general (though perhaps quite feasible in any given example).